# How to make a field unique

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation

How to make a field required in the schema of a list, I have this example, but the field is still not being required.

```
<Field ID="{xxxxxx-xxx....}" Type="Text" Name="Title" DisplayName="User" Required="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Title" MaxLength="255" AllowDuplicateValues="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="TRUE" Indexed="TRUE" />
```

Does anyone knows how can I do that?

> **I made a mistake, what I want to know is how to make a field UNIQUE VALUE in the schema of a list**

Comment: The Required="TRUE" should do it. Title is a reserved name in most cases (even tho you're prob just using that as an example)

Comment: I made a mistake, what I want to know is how to make  a field UNIQUE VALUE  in the schema of a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep these attributes:

```
Required="TRUE" EnforceUniqueValues="TRUE" Indexed="TRUE"
```

and remove:

```
AllowDuplicateValues="FALSE"
```

in both the Elements.xml and the Schema.xml of your list definition.

Comment: not working with the field Title (default of list)

Answer (score 0):

You already posted a part of the answer to your question. `Required="TRUE"` is the key to the solution.

First of all, the List Schema is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa543477%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

You could use SharePoint Designer. [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5KDSSOKZEJ0) is a video showing how to this for SharePoint 2010.

Or you can create a SharePoint Project in Visual Studio and add a list there. How to do this is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231593.aspx).

Comment: I made a mistake, what I want to know is how to make a field UNIQUE VALUE in the schema of a list

Comment: [There](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee536168(v=office.14).aspx) you go.

And [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms437580(v=office.15).aspx) for the field definition: `EnforceUniqueValues = "TRUE" | "FALSE"`